# Create different shapes of the same objects with its content

Tags: python, modifiers, displacement

I was trying to recreate the following screenshot from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IzL5GjFjcbU

[image]

The cells are quite different from each other and also their content (not visible in the pic) is animated and also variate from cell to cell.

They seem also arranged in an array, but somehow they fit in between the blood vessels. I can get an array of cells that variate but not this complicated. Also external cells are bigger than the internal part.

By using a displace modifier you can obtain subtle variations but not dramatic change in shapes so that they can fill the space nicely.

I don't think they did it manually.

My question is how can this be achieved in Blender? Do you need some python scripting to obtain something like that? I am wondering what's the workflow to do it.

Thanks!

Here is the result after particle emitter suggestion:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Tissue add on has this kid of tools. Have you tried that?

Comment: @Carlo thanks for the suggestion. I'm looking into that and I think it can help with increasing shape randomness, but it will not help to arrange the objects in that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a particle system. Here's one approach

1. Create a circle
2. Extrude it and scale the extrusion inward to the same radius as the base of the thing that is going up
3. add a lot of edge loops.
4. Then I would select all of the faces and delete "faces only"

This will create a circle with a lot of vertices.  [image: a circle with a lot of vertices]

Next I would create a collection of objects representing the cells.  (For my example I only created a cube)

Next I would create a particle system for the circle.

1. Set it to hair.
2. Emit from vertices.
3. Disable random order
4. Set the number to match the vertices
5. Render as collect (object in my example)
6. Use the collection of cells (cube) as the collection (object)
   [image: Particle system]

Finally you can use a vertex group to limit which vertices so you can draw the veins where the vertices won't have cells.[image: example with vein]

My result is too rigid but you can randomize the vertices a bit and so on.

You get about half the work done automatically this way but you have to do the rest to make it organic in any way.

Comment: Many thanks! I'm gonna try that!

Comment: Let me know if you need help using a collection instead of an object or want to see my blend file.

Comment: Sure, thanks. I'll post again the results and let you know.

Comment: I followed your suggestion and added the rendering in my question. I used a collection of 4 different cells. It's a little bit chaotic and not all the objects are filling the vertexes, but it's a good starting point! Please let me know what you think, thank you!

Comment: @Steven please read: [what should I do when someone answers my question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: @susu yes, I just wanted to finish the discussion before accepting

Comment: I like what you're doing. If you're not filling all of the vertices make sure you don't have 'random order' set and that you have set the number of particles high enough to have one particle per vertex. One thing I didn't mention is that you can dissolve specific vertices to create room for the veins.  I might make the inner circle smaller, but then delete parts of radials to create more room.